# Randomly Output A Number based on the percentage given

Tags: python-2.7, random

I am currently trying to make a Pokemon Game in Python, however, when you try to catch Pokemon, those legendary Pokemons wont share the same appear rate as normal Pokemons. Therefore I want to import the percentage randomness into the Python, in case you dont understand, this is what I suppose to happen:

Magikrap 10%

Greninja 1%

Lapras 1%

Psyduck 15%

and I want the Python to generate 10 Magikraps if I need it to random generate 100 Pokemons

I am wondering should I import random from Python or what should I do?
Thank you

Comment: Sure, that sounds good. Create a list of those Pokemon objects, and you could use the `random` method to randomly select items from the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from random import randint as r
ran = r(1,100)
if ran == "1":
    poke = "Lapras"
elif ran == "2":
    poke = ...
so on and so on...
print "You found",poke,"!"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Random.uniform](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.uniform). Then make a database that has the pokemon and their catch rate. You could even separate this based on area if you wanted to.

Something like:

```
import random

random.uniform(0,100)
```

Which in my case was 45.0757219

So you could build a list that looks like this. (Not actual code)

```
Magikrap 0,10.4

Greninja 10.4,11

Lapras 11,11.3

Psyduck 11.3,15
```

And then whatever range the number lands in, the player gets the pokemon associated with that range.

Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dictionary of Pokemon and their catch rate like: `catch_rate = {"Magikarp": 10}'. You would add more pokemon, of course. Then you could use:

```
import random
if random.randint(1, 100) < catch_rate[pokemon]:
    print "You caught a " + pokemon + "!"
```

This checks if the random is low enough to be less than the catch rate, and if it is, it is a success. You would need to assign  `pokemon` a value for this code to work.